# The Greatest Siblings

Tags: riddle

> We’re the Greatest of our siblings
>   Always best since days of yore
>   Our Least brother’s always nibbling
>   Now and then he gets one more
>
> First and last are far yet near
>   Fourth and fifth together chained
>   One through four are strange or queer
>   Five, six, seven are level planes
>
> Flavors are our favorite number
>   It describes our special quirk
>   With these clues you’re now encumbered
>   Knuckle down and get to work!

**Who are the seven Greatest siblings? Who is their Least brother (he’s not one of the seven)?**

Comment: If that said 5th and 6th are chained together I would have worked so hard to make the rainbow ROY G BIV fit this in some demented way. (also works nicely for the far yet near for first and last...) BAH.

Comment: Ya my first guess was the Weasley children tbh

Comment: This has got to have something to do with particle physics.

Comment: I was thinking moon phases for some reason (first phase takes place right after the last)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The seven are

> January, March, May, July, August, October, and December

The least is

> February

We’re the Greatest of our siblings
Always best since days of yore
Our Least brother’s always nibbling
Now and then he gets one more

> Greatest since they have 31 days. February has the least days with 28, but sometimes has 29 on a leap year.

First and last are far yet near
Fourth and fifth together chained
One through four are strange or queer
Five, six, seven are level planes

> January and December are 1 and 12, but January is one month from December. Edit from the comment: Four and five, July and August, are the seventh and eight months, so they're chained together. One through four are the first, third, fifth, and seventh months, which are odd. Perhaps August, October, and december are equally separated by two months, so they're level planes; or they're all even (level) at eight, ten, and twelve.

Flavors are our favorite number
It describes our special quirk
With these clues you’re now encumbered
Knuckle down and get to work!

> 31 flavors is a reference to Baskin Robins' flavors.

Comment: Excellent! For the second stanza, consider that the numbering might not be relative to ALL the siblings.

Comment: Now that I get it, I love the knuckle part.  (http://www.mathsisfun.com/measure/images/months-knuckles.jpg)

Comment: @qwertylpc Yessss I was hoping someone would pick up on that!